# Get n Least Significant Bits from an Int

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

This seems fairly straightforward, but I cant find an answer. If I have an int X, what is the best way to get N least significant bits from this int, in Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: @KaipaMSarma - that doesn't really answer his question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work for all non-negative N < <strike>33</strike> 32:

```
x & ((1 << N) - 1)
```

It's worth elaborating on how this works for `N == 31` <strike>and `N == 32`</strike>. For `N == 31`, we get `1 << N == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. When you subtract 1 from that, Java silently wraps around to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is exactly what you need. <strike>For `N == 32`, the 1 bit is shifted completely out, so `1 << N == 0`; then `(1 << N) - 1 == -1`, which is all 32 bits set.</strike>

For `N == 32`, this unfortunately doesn't work because (thanks, @zstring!) the `<<` operator only shifts by the right side mod 32. Instead, if you want to avoid testing for that case specially, you could use:

```
x & ((int)(1L << N) - 1)
```

By shifting a `long`, you get the full 32-bit shift, which, after casting back to an `int`, gets you 0. Subtracting 1 gives you -1 and `x & -1` is just `x` for any `int` value `x` (and `x` is the value of the lower 32 bits of `x`).

Comment: `1 << 32` is equal to integer value `1` so it will not work for `N == 32`.

Comment: @zstring -- Ooh. Nice catch! For an `int` left side, `<<` only uses the lower five bits of the right argument, so instead of shifting by 32, it shifts by 0. I'll have to fix my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ted's approach is likely to be faster but here is another approach

```
x << -N >>> -N
```

This shift all the bit up and then down to chop off the top bits.

```
int i = -1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
i = i << -5 >>> -5;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
```

prints

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111
```

Comment: Nice. Java automatically computes the shift quantity mod 32, so this is exactly the same as `x << (32 - N) >>> (32 - N)` (except that it avoids the two subtractions). I don't have any idea which is faster. My solution uses a shift, a subtract and a bit-wise AND. Yours uses two shifts and two negations (one if the compiler is clever or the programmer provides some help). For `N > 32`, my solution behaves as if `N == 32`. Yours always shifts by `(-N) % 32`, so the two are not equivalent for out-of-range `N` values.

Comment: Yes, with the modification that the shift quantity is computed mod 64.

Comment: The nice thing being I don't need to make assumptions about the bits size of my data type i.e. it could change later without some subtle bug appearing.

Comment: Yep. Much better than explicitly subtracting from 32 (or 64). I don't think my solution requires any assumptions either.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a mask. If you use the & bitwise operator you can then remove whatever bit you would want to remove (say the highest x bits);

```
int mask = 0x7FFFFFFF                 //Example mask where you will remove the 
                                      // most significant bit 
                                      // (0x7 = 0111b and 0xF = 1111b).
int result = numberToProcess & mask;  //And apply the mask with the &bitwise op.
```

The disadvantage to this is that you will need to make a mask for each bit, so perhaps this is better seen as another method of approach in general.